# Kotlin Poet super interface with type argument

Tags: android, kotlin, code-generation, kotlinpoet

I'm trying to generate an `object` which implements an interface with type parameter like the following example:

```
object HelloWorld : Feature<Intent>
```

I can generate the object that implements my interface like the following code:

```
val typeSpecBuilder = TypeSpec.objectBuilder("HelloWorld")
typeSpecBuilder.addSuperinterface(
      ClassName(
               "com.example.mylib",
               "Feature"
      )
```

How can I pass the `type argument` to the `interface`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import `plusParameter` manually:

```
import com.squareup.kotlinpoet.ParameterizedTypeName.Companion.plusParameter
```

And use like below:

```
val typeSpecBuilder = TypeSpec.objectBuilder(feature.featureName)
typeSpecBuilder.addSuperinterface(
      ClassName(
            "com.raqun.icarus.core",
            "Feature"
      ).plusParameter(ClassName("com.example.myawesomeclass", "MyAwesomeClass"))
)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `parameterizedBy()` method to use generic type. If it is not detected by IDE, you can import manually.